# Which key from which hash is this expression accessing?

Tags: perl

I am tracing a Perl script and I cannot understand what the following expression is supposed to do:

```
keys %{ $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port}->{$manager} }
```

I am trying to understand which key from which hash we are trying to access — from data, port or manager?

Below is the complete code:

```
foreach my $port ( keys %{$data->{net_assets_detail} } ) {    
        foreach my $manager (keys %{ $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port} } ) {          


    my $fund_value = MOA::CLSUtils::get_manager_fund_value( $port, $manager, $args->{end_date} );    
    $fund_value ||=0;    
    my $net_asset_value = $data->{net_assets_manager}->{$port}->{$manager};    
    $net_asset_value ||=0;    


        foreach my $tran_type (keys %{ $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port}->{$manager} } ) {                    
                my $value = $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port}->{$manager}->{$tran_type};                          
                print OUT"$port\t";    
                print OUT"$manager\t";    
                print OUT"$tran_type\t";    
                print OUT"$value\n";    

            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html

Comment: But it seems like there are three hashes: data, port and manager. How can we get data from all three?

Comment: What do you want to do? We have no way of knowing whether the terminal key is another hash reference or not, because you've only included one line of the program.

Comment: I print this value to the file

Comment: So... what is the question, exactly? What part don't you understand? Is it the loop? The call to `keys()`? The variables? Hash references?

Comment: Look at the complete code above now

Comment: I'm going to ask one more time: what part of the code don't you understand?

Comment: I am trying to understand which key from which hash we are trying to get %{ $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port}->{$manager}, from data, port or manager

Comment: It sounds like you need to `use Data::Dump; dd($data);`

Comment: use [Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to print the hash.
like `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($data);` you will know the structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the line part by part.

```
%{ $data->{net_assets_detail}->{$port}->{$manager} }
```

- There is a hashref called `$data`.
- Inside, there are some keys. One of them is `net_assets_detail`
- Inside is a hashref
- Inside, there are some keys. One of them is the value of `$port`
- Inside is a hashref
- Inside, there are some keys. One of them is the value of `$manager`

The `%{ ... }` is dereferencing the hashref, so built-ins that expect a hash can work on it.

The `keys` takes all the *keys* of the hash (which was dereferenced from the long thingy) and returns them as a *list*. The `foreach` iterates over that list, and puts each key into the lexical variable `$tram_type` that is available in the body of the loop.

Comment: Now I understand, Thank you

Comment: @osamuyl, please mark the answer as correct if it helped you understand/solve your issue.